# When configuring Snapshot for an ElasticSearch cluster, do I do that to every node?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, kibana

Sorry for what may be an obvious question. But I have a 3 node ElasticSearch cluster, and I want it to take a nightly snapshot that is sent to S3 for recovery. I have done this for my test cluster which is a single node. And I was starting to do it for my 3 node production cluster when I was left wondering if I have to configure the repository and snapshot on each node separately or can I just do it on one node via Kibana and then it will replicate that across the cluster? I have looked through the documentation but didn't see anything about this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to configure it in every node.

First you need to install the `repository-s3` plugin in every node, this is explained in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/repository-s3.html#repository-s3-install).

After that, you also need to add the access and secret keys in the elasticsearch-keystore of every node. ([documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/repository-s3-client.html#repository-s3-client)).

The rest of the configuration, creating the repository and setting the snapshots, are done through Kibana once.